# Are phosphenes not a common ophthalmological phenomena?

Tags: optometry, opthalmology, hallucinate-hallucogenic

I've been able to see them my entire life as far back as I can remember as a child (I am now 31 at this time of writing).  I had always assumed this to be something that everyone can perceive, but by random chance I happened to come across this [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphene) and based upon the word selection and connotation, it sounds like that isn't actually the case?